# Delphi Tokyo UpdateCheck Gone?

Tags: delphi, updatecheck

I cannot seem to find the "Check for Updates" feature in Delphi Tokyo.
Typically: **Start | All Programs | Embarcadero RAD Studio | Check for Updates**
I noticed this when trying to patch to 10.2.1.

UpdateCheck.exe was in the bin folder with Delphi as recently as Seattle (17.0). 
[image]

It doesn't seem to exist, at least not for me, Is there a way to automatically check for updates in Delphi Tokyo?  It is still documented.  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Check_for_Updates

I don't really mind occasionally checking myself, but this was a nice feature.

Thank you,

Comment: I noticed this too, very annoying

Comment: They also forgot BeyondCompare Lite.  They recently added it to GetIt.  https://twitter.com/marcocantu/status/849205534528086017?lang=en